# Mongodb node.js organised array result

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I have worked on a document whose current result is

```
{ "employee_details" : [{ 
    "name" : "Treasure Bliss Dwayne", 
    "work_details" : [{
        "shift" : [ "spray", "smoothing", "packaging", "shining"], 
        "worktime" : [ [ 5 ], [ ], [ 8 ], [ 10 ]] } 
    ]} 
]}
```

I have been looking for ways of producing the following output

```
{ "employee_details" : 
    [ 
        { "name" : "Treasure Bliss Dwayne"}, 
        { "spray":5},
        {"smoothing":},
        {"packaging":8},
        {"shining":10} 
    ]
}
```

Please how can I go about it

Comment: Are you looking for a query(mongodb) to do this or nodejs code(to work on the result) would also help?

Comment: I want to first of test it in mongodb query before porting to node.js/express.js

Comment: Not sure if you can get what you want directly but you can try experimenting $unwind https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: I have tried that but it did not work. the work is done inside $let var in clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "employee_details": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$employee_details",
        "as": "emp",
        "in": {
          "name": "$$emp.name",
          "work_details": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$$emp.work_details",
              "as": "aa",
              "in": {
                "$arrayToObject": {
                  "$map": {
                    "input": { "$range": [0, { "$size": "$$aa.shift" }] },
                    "as": "qq",
                    "in": {
                      "k": { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$aa.shift", "$$qq"] },
                      "v": {
                        "$ifNull": [
                          {
                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                              { "$arrayElemAt": ["$$aa.worktime", "$$qq"] },
                              0
                            ]
                          },
                          ""
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```